# Inserting elements into map with set value and printing the set

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert, set

I'd like to build a map with an integer key and a set value.  I'd like to know what the syntax for doing that should be.  Also, once I have the map filled with some key and value pairs, how should the set value be printed out?

```
map<int, set<int> > mymap;
map[node]= // Code to insert elements into set???
 for( map<int, set<int> >::iterator ii=mymap.begin(); ii!=mymap.end(); ++ii)
{ //Code to print map??? }
```

Also, is there some way to add elements to a set for a key that's already been created?  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: see here [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and here [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)

Comment: Thanks.  I looked at those, but there aren't any examples of the syntax I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert in the set you can use the method `insert`. If the map key doesn't exist (`node`), it will be created.

See the example:

```
node = 1; // a map key
map<int, set<int> > mymap;
mymap[node].insert(99); //insert 99 in the set corresponding to the map key 1

for( map<int, set<int> >::iterator ii=mymap.begin(); ii!=mymap.end(); ++ii)
{ 
    cout<< "Key: "<< ii->first << " value: ";
    for (set<int>::iterator it=ii->second.begin(); it!=ii->second.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
    cout << Lendl;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to add multiple integers to the set in a single insert?  Something like:  mymap[node].insert(99, 100, 101);

Comment: @Caulibrot [std::set::operator=()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/operator%3D) 3rd form.

Comment: @Caulibrot It's in the example section on [that page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) dude.

Comment: std::set<int> nums1 {3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 9};